# Why this code don't give null pointer exception?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, performance-testing

I'm little bit confused about below code, where I'm adding a `Fragment` inside a `Fragment`, `onCreateView()` method before adding it's `View`. From my  point of view as I did not yet set the `View` so when the `R.id.rv_container` will call to get the `FrameLayout` for that `Child Fragment` it will get `null` pointer exception but that's not happening. It working good.
So what is the reason of this? Why I'm wrong about `null` pointer exception?

**Fragment Class:**

```
public class Chats extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        initRvView();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat,
                container, false);
    }

    private void initRvView() {
        final String POST_RV = "chat_recycler";
        RecyclerViewFragment recyclerViewFragment = (RecyclerViewFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(POST_RV);
        if (recyclerViewFragment == null) {
            recyclerViewFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment(FROM_MESSAGING);
        }
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rv_container,
                        recyclerViewFragment,
                        POST_RV)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment Layout (R.layout.fragment_chat):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rv_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **If you look at the code `initRvView()` method is calling before set the `View` but didn't showing any `null` pointer exception.**

Comment: Would you provide your logcat as well?

Comment: @jle there is no error. it's work fine but that's where i get puzzled how that work fine?

Comment: actually setting fragment using fragment manager's replace or add method does not require you to 1st inflate the layout file. It just need the id of the framelayout or whatever viewgroup you are using to wrap the fragment.

Comment: ohh, if that's the reason than it's good. i thought there no null exception this time but some time it may show. so thanks for clear the fact.